# Windographer installed with no errors but won't run under wine

Tags: windows, wine, 15.04

I have Ubuntu Mate 15.04 and I have successfully installed wine from the `.deb` package they provide. Then I have successfully (at least with no errors) installed a Windows program by right-clicking on it and selecting the "Open with Wine" options.

I can't seem to run the program, though. I have tried left-clicking on the program icon, right-clicking on it and then running it with wine, and running it from the CLI with `wineconsole "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windographer\Windographer.exe"` and with `wine "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windographer\Windographer.exe"`. These last two give me this output in the terminal:

```
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33fbe0 (nil)): stub
fixme:msxml:domelem_setAttributeNode (0x18c790)->(0x18c8f4 0x33fb88): semi-stub
fixme:msxml:domelem_setAttributeNode (0x18c790)->(0x18ca9c 0x33fb88): semi-stub
fixme:msxml:domelem_setAttributeNode (0x18c790)->(0x18c7f4 0x33fb88): semi-stub
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000007 at address 0xf743615a (thread 0029), starting debugger...
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

**EDIT**
Instaling wine from the repository gives me the same error.
PlayOnLinux also does not work, but I can't get any error from it.

Comment: Page Fault is a runtime failure in the program or in Wine.  That's likely meaning a failure in the program itself being run (and a crash in the program, not Wine)

Comment: The .deb file on the site of wine is for Ubuntu 14.04. Have you tried to install it using sudo apt-get install wine? Have you tried the wine fork PlayOnLinux?

Comment: @wb9688 I'm trying those right now. Didn't know about PlayOnLinux. Installing from the repository gives me the same error.

Comment: @wb9688 neither of your suggestions worked. Will it mame a difference if I install it from source?

Comment: @TomCho Likely not, but consider of course that the error is that the program itself is triggering a page fault on read access.  Have you tried a 32bit wine prefix instead?  (assuming you are on 64bit)

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @Zanna No, but things change a lot in 2 and a half years. You might be able to today

Answer (score 0):

Wine is not showing the program crash. I have that too.
Play on Linux might help but really there is not much to do. Some programs work on wine some don't. There is no specifique way of repairing that. Could you please tell us what program it is you are trying to run ?

If you really need to run that program then you have always got the choice of using a virtual machine inside your primary os (for you mate 15.04). The easiest way is to download [virtual box](http://www.virtualbox.org) or do it per command line

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

You could also dual boot into Windows. This would be easier to explain per video. Just search it up on youtube.

Since wine is crashing you also should make sure to save your documents... anything which is open. Wine crashed on me and I lost unsaved data.

Sorry for the inconvenience
hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you, but I am aware of these options. I was trying to save me the trouble of having to use a virtual machine (even more to install windows alongside my ubuntu).

Comment: Yes i know the frustration of unsupport.

Comment: Also what program is it that you want?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that question.  You can actually see it from the commands I used (that's why I didn't mention). It's called windographer.